# Proof of Convergence in Probability implies Convergence in Distribution

Tags: probability-theory

I am reviewing the proof that convergence in probability implies convergence in distribution, and there is one step that I’m not understanding.

Namely, at the end we have

$F(t-\epsilon)$ $\leq$ $\lim_{n\to\infty}$ $F_n(t)$ $\leq$ $F(t+\epsilon)$ $\implies$  $\lim_{n\to\infty}$ $F_n(t)$ = F(t)

Why is this the cAse?

Comment: let $\epsilon \to 0$.

Answer (score 0):

By definition of convergence in distribution we only have to show that  $F_n(t) \to F(t)$ when $F$ is continuous at $t$. In this case we get $F(t) \leq \lim \inf F_n(t) \leq \lim \sup F_n(t) \leq F(t)$ by letting $\epsilon \to 0$. Hence $\lim F_n(t)$ exists and equals $F(t)$.

Comment: Thank you, i guess the key part I’m missing is why taking the limit essentially negates the epsilon, that is, making $F_n(t)$ both greater than and less than F(t)